# javascript get current day and month issue

Tags: javascript

Using the javascript code below I get month = 3, day = 5, y = 2014.  Of course I expect month 4 and day 18.

```
var TodayDate = new Date();
var d = TodayDate.getDay();
var m = TodayDate.getMonth();
var y = TodayDate.getFullYear();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is not jQuery code, but only Javascript. See Date javascript documentation.

Comment: @VincentDecaux  I didn't notice that I was using JavaScript and not jQuery.  Would jQuery be better/faster?  And if so, what jQuery function should it be? Thank you for catching my mistake.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

you have to use `getMonth() + 1` to get month (zero-index based) because javascript implementation followed JAVA & that is how `java.util.Date` did it.

`getDay()` - gives you `5` for today being Friday(6th Day of the week. *Sunday **0*** to *Saturday **6***)

`getDate()` - gives you `18` (today's date)

Comment: Krishna, thank you.  What about .getDay() why is it not correct?

Comment: I have a tough time deciding to whom I should give the Answer since both answered at the same time :)

Comment: @Hidalgo - Haha.. I will leave that to you, although I must say I answered a few seconds before Praveen did. I rest my case. I won't hold it against you if you accepted his answer though ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation about getMonth() as zero-index based.

Answer (score 7):

it is [**`getDate()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) not [**`getDay()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)

```
var d = TodayDate.getDate();  //it returns the date 
var m = TodayDate.getMonth()+1; //returns the index of the month array
                                //for our convenience we add 1 to it
```

[month](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) in `Date` object is an `array` which starts with `0 -11` (Jan starting with 0 and dec ends with 11)

FYI:

**getDay()** - returns the day(ie, friday in number as 5 ) => Sun starts with 0 and Sat ends with 6 [Again it is an array]

Comment: TodayDate is not defined!! like   


var TodayDate = new Date();